# Laravel 5.4 - Create user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm integrating Facebook login in my web app, but I get this error:

> ErrorException in SessionGuard.php line 407: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface
>   Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, string given, called in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/shop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php
>   on line 294 and defined

I saw that the issue is when I create the new user:

```
public function findOrCreateUser($user, $provider)
{
    $authUser = User::where('provider_id', $user->id)->first();
    // if user exist login
    if ($authUser) {
        return $authUser;
    }

    // if user don't exist - Create new user
    $test = DB::table('users')->insert([
              'name'     => $user->name,
              'email'    => $user->email,
              'provider' => $provider,
              'provider_id' => $user->id
            ]);

    return 'Hello'; // just try if it work!
}
```

User is created correctly but I get the error above. I can't see my message "Hello". If I replace the create method like this:

```
return User::create([
      'name'     => $user->name,
      'email'    => $user->email,
      'provider' => $provider,
      'provider_id' => $user->id
]);
```

it works well. But I don't want stop after create user; I would like return another view.

Answer (score 2):

There is several ways how to insert new row into table in laravel.

One way to do it is

```
User::create([
      'name'     => $user->name,
      'email'    => $user->email,
      'provider' => $provider,
       'provider_id' => $user->id
 ]);
return view('your_view');
```

But you need to have this in your model (for mass assignment)

```
protected $fillable = ['name','email','provider','provider_id'];
```

Other way to insert new row is next

```
$user_database = new User;
$user_database->name = $user->name;
$user_database->email = $user->email;
$user_database->provider = $provider;
$user_database->provider_id = $user->id;
$user_database->save();
return view('your_view');
```

Hope it helps you. For more additional help check [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this line is causing the problem `$test = DB::table('users')->inse...` check in if condition

```
if ($authUser) {
    dd('here comes the boom.....');
    return $authUser;
}
```

Also keep in mind `$authUser` is `User` type object where as `$test` is `boolean`!